# Deleted Comments

Tags: discussion

from [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60723/how-do-i-know-if-a-partition-is-ext2-ext3-or-ext4/60725#60725) If the previous comments of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60723/how-do-i-know-if-a-partition-is-ext2-ext3-or-ext4/60756#60756) is deleted.

how I can understand the comment below my answer. 
I feel there should be a history of comments so that we can understand the contents.

It may seem to be visible, but a lot of misunderstanding can occur.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People are constantly trying to add new comments features; they're meant to be lightweight, they don't need histories and timelines and suggested edits and downvoting and all the other things people have suggested. Mods can see deleted comments if something like this really does come up, but since Warren wrote both of those comments I'm pretty sure it's not going to be a problem in this case

Comment: why didn't you put all the question and their comments in a single page so that in future it is easy to refer them if they become illogical??

Comment: @harish.venkat I don't know what you mean; the question and its comments are on a single page

Comment: @Micheal: If i remove my above comment the whole argument becomes illogical.so why don't we have a feature that if the user who posted the question can delete all the comments..once the question is closed atleast??

Comment: @harish.venkat Because a majority of the time comments are used to point out mistake the OP made, so we probably shouldn't let the OP delete them

Comment: @Micheal: I got it....it is too complex :-)

Comment: Do you have (as moderator) a "history-button" like I mentioned below for Mantis? If so - what is the reason not to give that button to all users - say above 200 reputation?

Comment: @Nils We can see when a comment was deleted and who deleted it, but it's not particularly user-friendly, and the only reason it really exists is to figure out why a comment thread doesn't make sense anymore so we can clean it up

Answer (score 5):

Comments aren't meant to be an important feature of the site. For discussion, there's [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

If comments become nonsensical because other comments have been deleted, delete them (if they're yours) or flag them as obsolete if they're someone else's.

Answer (score 0):

When I do delete a comment of mine, I flag the corresponding comments as "outdated". Normally the comment-owners then delete their comments, too.

I do this if comments get lengthy and/or have been integrated as edit into the question or answer.

But I get your point. Mantis (an open-source-bug-tracking-system) has a - IMHO - nice way to handle edits and deleted comments: There is a history-button, where you can see who changed what and when (if you like to see that information).